# How do I edit or add to Notepad++ HTML/CSS autocomplete?

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, autocomplete

Could anyone tell me how to go about editing the existing CSS and/or HTML autocomplete language in Notepad++? My Google-fu has let me down and I can't find an answer.

In essence, I want to add some CSS3 to the autocomplete and to edit some of the existing entries to suit my needs.

I'm using v.5.7 on Win7 btw.

Answer (score 11):

I think you can just add the relevant new keywords to the `langs.xml` file within the Notepad++ directory (back it up first, the usual warnings, etc). But, I believe this will do syntax highlighting only.

So, if you then go in to the `plugins\APIs` subdirectory you can edit the relevant `.xml` to also provide auto completion.

Comment: Many thanks, it worked perfectly. Please consider yourself draped in copious good karma.

Comment: which is apparently better than getting the best answer. =P

Comment: @JoeP would you please mark this as the answer if you found it helpful :) I did +1