# How can I add more autocomplete options to Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I edit or add to Notepad++ HTML/CSS autocomplete?](https://superuser.com/questions/166940/how-do-i-edit-or-add-to-notepad-html-css-autocomplete)

I created many functions in PHP and I want to add them to the "autocomplete" of Notepad++.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Auto_Completion) taken from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893761/how-can-i-enable-auto-complete-support-in-notepad) (it has some description, didn't want to steal an answer)