# Custom word library for notepad++ autocomplete

Tags: notepad++, autocomplete

So, there's already a question about this here, from back in 2010: [How do I edit or add to Notepad++ HTML/CSS autocomplete?](https://superuser.com/questions/166940/how-do-i-edit-or-add-to-notepad-html-css-autocomplete)

Since then though, we've gone from version 5.7 to 6.6.9

Using the instructions in that answer, I can't get it working.

Every month I listen to a recording of a wine club tasting and discussing various wines. I write it down so they can then use that text as a summary for their club magazine. These recordings are filled with technical terms and usually last from 2 hours to 3 hours.

So, I make a lot of mistakes, typing down names of wines, grapes and domains phonetically.

Having a list of these terms that I can add to when I find them would be really great.

I tried the suggestions from the other answer: editting the langs.xml file(which has been replaced by langs.model.xml now) and making my own xml file in the plugins/API folder. But nothing is showing up in the syntax list and nothing is showing up in the autocomplete.

So something must have changed or I'm doing it wrong. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

In editor **SynWrite**, you can customize HTML and CSS autocomplete lists. See files *.ini in folder "Data\autocomplete".